# Get index of object in list based on equality of state of object

Tags: python, list

```
class Shape():
    def __init__(self, n_sides, name):
        self.n_sides = n_sides
        self.name = name

def generate_shapes():
    return [Shape(4, 'square'), Shape(3, 'triangle'), Shape(4, 'rectangle')]

def generate_one_shape():
    return Shape(4, 'square')

shapes = generate_shapes()
one_shape = generate_one_shape()

shapes.index(one_shape)
```

I get an error as follows, since list.index() superficially compares the objects.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list_remove_object_by_value.py", line 14, in <module>
    shapes.index(one_shape)
ValueError: <__main__.Shape instance at 0x7efffbbcec68> is not in list
```

I would like list.index(one_shape) to return index as 0.

How can I get index of an instance of class Shape in a list efficiently using another instance of class Shape having the same values of attributes?

Comment: try defining `__eq__` for `Shape`

Comment: What if there are *multiple* such elements, or *none* at all?

Comment: If there are multiple such instances, I still need only the index of the first such element in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define an `__eq__` method.

```
class Shape():
    def __init__(self, n_sides, name):
        self.n_sides = n_sides
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """self == other"""
        if isinstance(other, Shape):
            # We can only compare if `other` is a Shape as well
            return self.n_sides == other.n_sides and self.name == other.name
        return NotImplemented

    def __ne__(self, other):
        """self != other"""
        eq = Shape.__eq__(self, other)
        return NotImplemented if eq is NotImplemented else not eq
```

What operators like `in` and `index` do is check if any of the items `==` each other. This `__eq__` method defines what happens when `==` is called with the two objects. By default, it checks if they are exactly the same object, but this checks if they are both `Shape`s, and have the same `n_sides` and `name`.

Comment: While you're at it, you should also provide `__ne__` and `__hash__`, or set `__hash__ = None` to make the objects unhashable if they shouldn't be hashable. (Python 3 handles some of this automatically, but Python 2 isn't going to die for a while.)

Comment: Will this still work if one of the class attributes is a floating point number?

Comment: @AdityaBarve They would have to be exactly equivalent. A common trick is instead of `float_a == float_b`, you do `abs(float_a - float_b) < 0.01` to check if they are withing `0.01` of each other to account for rounding errors. You can choose other numbers as well.